# how to downgrade the react native version from 0.60.4 to 0.59

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a react-native project of version 0.60.4. a third party module(react-native-webrtc) is not supported for that version so I trying to downgrade the react-native version.

I tried that by simply changing the package on react-native in package.json.then getting an error given below.
`Build input file cannot be found: 'XXXXXX/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi/jsi/jsi.cpp'`

Comment: what is the problem of react-native-webrtc in version 0.60.4? can you add your errors?

Comment: react-native-webrtc is not supporting for react-native 0.60.4. here is the link

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/issues/666

Comment: this problem related to androidX. It doesn't about react-native-webrtc. I have this problem about other package like react-native-camera and rn-fetch-blob and etc. you can follow my solution explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57765693/4592051

Comment: ok thank you i will check it once

Comment: [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod “react-native-webrtc”:
In Podfile:
 react-native-webrtc (from `../node_modules/react-native-webrtc`)

Specs satisfying the `react-native-webrtc (from` ../node_modules/react-native-webrtc`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher

Comment: @Majidlotfinia getting the above error while linking the module

Comment: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

follow this..might help